# HighCharts - HighStock - Show Date for Candlestick & Volume

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using the HighCharts graphing software and am trying to show the date labels on the x axis below the stock graph; it currently shows below the volume graph only.

How can I do this?

Here are the chart options I am using (removed irrelevant ones to save space)
JSFiddle link below

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector: {
            inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
            selected: 1
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
```

[JSFille Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? These two series are sharing the same xAxis, so even if you show dates below the stock graph, they would be same as the ones below volume graph.

Comment: I think it would easier to read; based on screen resolution you may have to scroll down to see the xAxis lables on the volume graph.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible without creating a new xAxis, but that will make two series not aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two xAxis, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/phtd7r1t/2/

```
 xAxis: [{
            offset: 15
        },{
            linkedTo:0,
            offset: -76
 }],
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of the positioning options to achieve this. If the height is dynamic it might be a bit difficult, but for static height charts this approach should work fine.

First edit the `yAxis[1].top` to be `'73%'` (moving the "Volume" chart further down to create a gap).

Then offset your x-axis with `xAxis: { offset: -81 }` to move it in between the two charts.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/phtd7r1t/) of the result.